# getting Unsafe assignment of an `any` value using useTheme from next-themes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, eslint

I have just one small problem. But I really don't see the error. I'm getting this eslint error. But everything is correctly typed

I using `Typescript` and `next.js` and the `next-themes` package to create a darkModeToggle

```
import { useTheme } from 'next-themes'
const { systemTheme, theme, setTheme } = useTheme()
```

eslint error:

```
Unsafe assignment of an `any` value.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
```

the types

```
const systemTheme: "dark" | "light" | undefined
const theme: string | undefined
const setTheme: (theme: string) => void
(alias) useTheme(): UseThemeProps
```

It would be great if someone could help me. Because I think it's my fault and not the package's.

Comment: Which line of code specifically is throwing the ESLint error?

Comment: the useTheme line

Comment: Did you solve the eslint error?